# OpenGL state changes made in glutKeyboardFunc are not visible immediately

Tags: c++, opengl, glut

I have a function glutKeyboardFunc(keyboard), where keyboard has:

```
void keyboard(unsigned char key, int x, int y){
    float alpha = 1.0;
    switch(key){
    case 'c':
        glClearColor(1,0,0,alpha);
        printf("success");
        break;
    }
}
```

This is a summary of the function; it works properly, but only once some other action has occurred.  For instance, the printf statement reports success immediately on keystroke 'c', but the background color does not become active until I click somewhere else on the canvas.  I want all keystrokes to have an immediate effect.

Comment: Needs more code (like your glutDisplayFunc implementation).  Also the title is confusing as glutkeyboardFunc has nothing to do with the mouse.

Comment: You are right, the title is a bit misleading but I think the question sums it up well.  I would add in the display function but a commenter has already answered my problem, so there is no need.  I'll accept the answer when I can (8 minutes)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to refresh the screen :

```
void keyboard(unsigned char key, int x, int y){
    float alpha = 1.0;
    switch(key){
    case 'c':
        glClearColor(1,0,0,alpha);
        printf("success");
        glutPostRedisplay(); // trigger the screen redisplay
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I just need to get used to having to put that function everywhere I guess.

Comment: alternatively he could follow convention and use glutIdleFunc

Comment: It would be better to set some program variable instead of calling glClearColor directly. As soon as you're setting clear colors multiple times per rendering a frame (and believe me, sooner than later you will!) doing it in the input event handler will break.

Comment: @datenwolf What do you mean with calling glClearColor directly? As far as I know, glutPostRedisplay() will set some variable to trigger the redisplay as soon as it can, therefore no need to additional variable. Or, am I wrong?

Comment: @BЈовић: What if on your display functions you're drawing into multiple regions (think minimap, HUD, augmented realtivy overlay) and hence set the clear color multiple times there? As a general rule OpenGL calls that can be considered drawing calls (and clearing is sort of a drawing operation) should be placed *only* in the display function and nowhere else.